to thin lines, flickery,problem with house

I dont know what I did but I didnt had these lines the whole time,they just popped out.
I had some problems so I undid a lot and redid, like I pressed ctrl z until it stopped doing smth and then i redid it sometimes back, it was chaotic. Now I noticed these lines and i think i did something wrong? Its in my viewport because Im still modelling.
I cant move on because I think I need to fix something or either it will distract me later. Can someone help me please

I noticed some more weird lines and dont know how to delete  them properly at the edges (these on the picture i could dissolve)
like at some point everything went wrong



I cant make a proper screeenshot from the screen because i need to move to  make a proper one, and if i stop the lines are going like in the last picture
blend file v4.1


That first images is showing a moire pattern so I guess it is a photo of your screen taken with your phone's camera. Please us Blender's built-in screenshot generator which will eliminate distortion from external sources. Use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question and add the image to that in future.

It looks as if you may have overlapping geometry. Go into wireframe mode with Shift-Z in Edit mode and take and post another screenshot. As @StefLAncien says sharing your Blend file would also be helpful.

I checked the provided Blender file using version 3.6.8, and I failed to reproduce the reported defaults even moving the view point. Just in case version 3.6.8 "sanitized" your file, here is a link to upload it.

StefLAncien i dont really understand what you mean by sanitized. When i open the file nothing changes.
